# Python - RuntimeError: Please destroy the QApplication singleton before creating a new QApplication instance

Tags: python

I'm following a Python tutorial for beginners. This tutorial has me write code to display a window called 'real_world.ui'. I wrote the coding according to the tutorial which displays the window on the tutorial instructor's computer system. When I ran the app on my system, I got this runtime error. From what I see in the coding, there seems to be just one line that creates the app. The error seems to be telling me that line is being called many times. Looks like it's a recursion problem in the coding. I'm new to Python and I'm looking to just have that line execute 1 time.

```
line 32, in Main
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
RuntimeError: Please destroy the QApplication singleton before creating a new QApplication instance.
```

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

import sys
from os import path
from PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType

import sqlite3

folder_path = '/Users/emad-ud-deen/Development/Python/Practice/Real World Database App/'

# Load the window.
#-----------------
FORM_CLASS, _=loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname('__file__'), folder_path + 'real_world.ui'))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.HandleButtonClicks()

    def HandleButtonClicks(self):
        print('At HandleButtonClicks')

def Main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Coding for real_world.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>747</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Parts Inventory Manager</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_background">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>721</width>
      <height>541</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap>sky3.jpg</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget_inventory">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>311</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="tabPosition">
     <enum>QTabWidget::North</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="tabShape">
     <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_inventory_details">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Inventory Details</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_inventory_details">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>17</x>
        <y>40</y>
        <width>581</width>
        <height>221</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: wheat;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
      </property>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ID</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Reference</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Part Name</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Min Area</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Max Area</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>No. Of Holes</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Min Diameter</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Max Diameter</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Count</string>
       </property>
      </column>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_count_inventory_details">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>300</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>42</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_search_inventory_details">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>499</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>32</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Search</string>
      </property>
      <property name="default">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_search_for_count_inventory_details">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>17</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>281</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Search for references that are &lt;= a count:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="inventory_statistics">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Inventory Statistics</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_top_3_references">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>17</x>
        <y>110</y>
        <width>441</width>
        <height>151</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: wheat;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
      </property>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Reference</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Part Name</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Count</string>
       </property>
      </column>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_top_3_references">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>17</x>
        <y>90</y>
        <width>291</width>
        <height>16</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Top 3 references with minimum inventory level:</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_check">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>470</x>
        <y>170</y>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>32</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Check</string>
      </property>
      <property name="default">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_statistics">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>17</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>441</width>
        <height>71</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: wheat;
</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_maximum_holes_amount_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>360</x>
         <y>40</y>
         <width>21</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>0</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_maximum_holes">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>220</x>
         <y>40</y>
         <width>141</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Max. Number of Holes:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_minimum_holes">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>220</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>141</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Min. Number of Holes:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_minimum_holes_amount">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>360</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>21</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>0</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_total_part_types_amount">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>120</x>
         <y>40</y>
         <width>21</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>0</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_total_references_amount">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>120</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>21</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>0</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_total_references">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>111</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Total References:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_total_part_types">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>40</y>
         <width>111</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Total Part Types:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="edit_inventory">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Edit Inventory</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_search_edit_inventory">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>499</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>32</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Search</string>
      </property>
      <property name="default">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>22</x>
        <y>50</y>
        <width>571</width>
        <height>211</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: wheat;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_minimum_diameter">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>464</x>
         <y>80</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_count">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>354</x>
         <y>140</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Count:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_part_name">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>134</x>
         <y>80</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_maximum_area">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>24</x>
         <y>140</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Max Area:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_minimum_area">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>134</x>
         <y>110</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_reference">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>134</x>
         <y>50</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_minimum_diameter">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>354</x>
         <y>80</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Min Diameter:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_reference_maximum_diameter">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>464</x>
         <y>110</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_minimum_area">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>24</x>
         <y>110</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Min Area:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_part_name">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>24</x>
         <y>80</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Part Name:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_number_of_holes">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>464</x>
         <y>50</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_number_of_holes">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>334</x>
         <y>50</y>
         <width>121</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Number of Holes:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_maximum_area">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>134</x>
         <y>140</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_maximum_diameter">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>354</x>
         <y>110</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Max Diameter:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_reference">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>24</x>
         <y>50</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Reference:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_ID_value">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>135</x>
         <y>19</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;
background-color:BurlyWood;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_edit_reference_3">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>26</x>
         <y>20</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">font: 15pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ID:</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_count">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>463</x>
         <y>140</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: cornsilk;
font: 13pt &quot;.AppleSystemUIFont&quot;;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_natigation">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>170</y>
         <width>291</width>
         <height>31</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_go_to_beginning">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;&lt;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_previous">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>80</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_next">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&gt;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_go_to_end">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>220</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&gt;&gt;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_database_controls">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>310</x>
         <y>170</y>
         <width>251</width>
         <height>31</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_update_row">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>71</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Update</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_delete_row">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>71</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Delete</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_insert_row">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>170</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>71</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Add</string>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_title">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>721</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>64</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: gold;
background-color: SaddleBrown;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Parts Inventory Manager</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_refresh">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>570</x>
      <y>451</y>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Refresh</string>
    </property>
    <property name="default">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>747</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def Main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    ...
```

is recursive, I guess it should be `window = MainWindow()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I made the change but get this new error: line 24, in __init__
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
RuntimeError: You can't initialize an object twice!

Comment: You are calling both `super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)` and `QMainWindow.__init__(self)` you should only use the former. If you are coding for python3 you should use `super()` without any arguments, i.e. `super().__init__(parent)`.